# Correct way to set kotlin coroutine scope for backend app

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

What is the correct way to set coroutine scope -

1.Implementing scope

```
@Service
class MyServiceImpl : MyService, CoroutineScope {
    private val job: Job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100).asCoroutineDispatcher()
    override fun get(): String {
        launch {....}
        return "Result"
    }}
```

`
2. Without implementing

```
@Service
class MyServiceImpl : MyService {
    private val scope = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100).asCoroutineDispatcher()
    override fun get(): String {
        GlobalScope.launch(scope) {....}
        return "Result"
    }}
```

Or just use GlobalScope without any context??

Comment: One thing that stings the eye here is that in the first example you create a new 100-thread pool each time you fetch the `coroutineContext`. This should be extracted and reused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no correct way, all three variants are useful in different scenarios.

1. **Implementing an own coroutine scope**:
   If the lifetime of your coroutines depends on the lifetime of another object. Especially useful in UI applications, e.g. Android, if you need to destroy all pending coroutines, when the starting activity is destroyed, see https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#structured-concurrency-lifecycle-and-coroutine-parent-child-hierarchy.
2. **Create a scope from a thread pool**: If your coroutines should run in a common thread pool. In this scenario the lifetime of a new coroutine is not depending from this scope, but from the outer coroutine:

   ```
   val fixedThreadPoolContext = newFixedThreadPoolContext(100, "background")
   launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
       withContext(fixedThreadPoolContext) {
           //parent job is from the outer coroutine
       }
       //or
       val asyncResult = async(fixedThreadPoolContext) {
           //parent job is from the outer coroutine
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Use global scope**: If you like to start some background coroutines, which are not depending on any other object. Typically is it better to provide an own scope that is bound to your application object or some global singleton. Then you can provide your own exception handler, etc

For a backend service, I would use an own global threadpool dispatcher Then you have the control over the size. Be aware, that GlobalScope uses the CPU count as a parameter to define the pool size. That's great for CPU bounded tasks, but not for IO tasks, like database access.

Comment: Thank you, what should i use in my case? I have a REST-api backend app build on springboot. And there  i have a case where i need to save data to database asynchronously. Firstly i used usual threadpool and submit tasks, but i decided to try coroutines.

Comment: I would create an own global threadpool dispatcher for this. Then you have the control over the size. Be aware, that GlobalScooe uses the cpu count as a parameter to define the pool size. That's great for cpu bounded tasks, but not for IO tasks, like database access.

Comment: @Rene I don't see too many examples using `Dispatchers.IO`. This example of using a database seems like a perfect use case for:


`class MyServiceImpl : MyService, CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) {`


Would the above code be a good approach?

Comment: @jrk Yes it is. `Dispatchers.IO` is a good default dispatcher exactly for blocking IO